# URI not rewritten although it matches rewrite condition

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

One of my clients has multiple domains that all point to one webspace. To avoid duplicate content the URIs get rewritten to all point to one place. Using the code below that works for all but two of them. As far as I can tell there is nothing special about them.

Sadly I don't have administrative access to the domains, but to the best of my understanding the .htaccess should be enough.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

The rule:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^example\.com$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^ http://example\.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Are you sure mod_rewrite is turned on? If you remove the `<IfModule>` container, do you get a 500 server error?

Comment: Yes `RewriteEngine On` is a bit further up the .htaccess and it does work with some domains.